# Installing opengeo on Arch Linux

Tags: installation, boundless-suite, linux

I am trying to install the opengeo suite (community) for a project I have. The thing is that my Linux distribution is Arch Linux, for which the package manager is pacman and not apt-get as it is the case in Ubuntu.

Is it possible to install it on Arch Linux?

The installation manual says that it provides packages for both debian and red hat, but is possible to build a package from sources somewhere?

I know they have a git repository, however, I cannot see how to build a package from it (my knowledge of writing PKGBUILDs is slim at best).

Answer (score 1):

I also run arch linux.

When I set up geonode (a component of the suite) on my arch system, I used [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) with ubuntu linux. There are so many [parts](http://suite.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/installation/linux/details.html#list-of-packages) to the suite, so many things that could conflict with existing arch packages that it would likely be quite the challenge to get working.

If you really wanted to, you probably could translate the [open geo build instructions](https://github.com/opengeo/suite#prerequisites) into [your own package](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Creating_Packages), but that sounds like a lot of work.